# ERROR: ld.so: object 'libhugetlbfs.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored

Tags: linux, huge-pages

i'm trying run a simple malloc program to see whether my hugepage environment has been properly setup. the libhugetlbfs is installed in the default system directory only /usr/local. OS is RHEL 6.7. I checked that the libhugetlbfs.so is ther in /usr/lib64 folder. When i run i code with
    **HUGETLB_MORECORE=yes LD_PRELOAD=libhugetlbfs.so**

the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   double *x;
   int y,i;
   y = 15000000;
   x = (double *)malloc(y*sizeof(double));
   if (x != NULL)
   {
       printf("\nmalloc successful\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("malloc unsuccesfull");
   }

 }
```

output gives

```
**ERROR: ld.so: object 'libhugetlbfs.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.**
malloc successful
```

its clear that the malloc dint happen using hugepage. I checked all environment variables.. not able to find problem.. any sugestion???

Answer (score 1):

It means that libhugetlbfs.so is not found.

You have to specify in `LD_PRELOAD` the full path:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/your/path/libhugetlbfs.so
```

Therefore, open a console and type

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/your/path/libhugetlbfs.so

export HUGETLB_MORECORE=yes

./your_binary
```

Comment: Hi, The file libhugetlbfs.so already exists in /usr/lib64/ directory, this directory is also standard lib directory. Infact as per your sugestion copied the file from /usr/lib64 to /usr/lib. its not taking. same error is comming.

Comment: Hi.. i dint get "compiling library". I installed the library using yum.

Comment: oh... every where i see that, to use hugepages need to use this command during execution  "HUGETLB_MORECORE=yes LD_PRELOAD=libhugetlbfs.so ./executable". I dont know how to link the hugepage library during compiling. can u give compiling flag for this??

Comment: Tried in another console by exporting and executing the binary separately.... same error.....

Comment: No... claudio....... its working....... while compiling i called -O optimisation flags for compiler and executed it regularly... its taking now.... i could even see the hugepages being used....

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing error as below

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib64/libjemalloc.so.1' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded
```

Below were my steps resolved the error for me.

**Go to the path /usr/lib64 and lok for the libjemalloc* using below commands**

```
  #cd /usr/lib64
  #ls | grep libjemalloc
```

**if you dont find you dont have that package installed in your system**

```
  $sudo yum whatprovides libjemalloc*
  $sudo yum install jemalloc-3.6.0-1.amzn2.x86_64
```